# Identifying a bug

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I found this bug ( vary in size )after deep cleaning to my bedroom today exactly in my bed sheets and window sill and my desk , can someone help me identify them

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please provide your location as well as size and preferably higher quality images of your specimens. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

These are two different species of [true bugs (Heteroptera)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heteroptera).
One of their unique characteristics which distinguish them from other insect groups are their forewings (the so-called "hemielytron", for a detailed figure see [here](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Heter-hemielytron.gif)) which are hardened at the base (~ 2/3, in red) and membranous at the tips (~ 1/3, in blue) and folded flat over the abdomen when at rest.

Assuming, these photos were taken somewhere in the Palaearctis (North America, Europe or Asia), I suspect

- to the left is a [birch bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleidocerys_resedae) (id characteristics ***from this photo***: mostly translucent forewings, elongated and red-brown head, yellow-brownish body, relatively large eyes, last antenna segment club-shaped) and
- to the right a member of the genus [*Stenodema*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stenodema) (id characteristics ***from this photo***: yellow-brown and elongated-oval body, large scutellum, long antenna and legs), relatively small eyes; *Stenodema* species camouflage themselves as grass grains on which they feed on).

Both species feed on plants (mostly birches, but also other wooden plants and grasses, respectively) and moved into your apartment accidentally.

[image: Kleidocerys resedae and Stenodema sp]

Comment: Good answer, but it could be improved by providing information on why you think these are the correct identifications.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I added some more details on how I id'ed these species...

Comment: Excellent answer now!